# how to put a text on the top of an png image using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to use a png picture as a background for my excel reports, an Add a text "number" on the top of the picture.

is there's away to do that.

This is my code:

```
$objDrawingbackground = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawingbackground->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objDrawingbackground->setName('background');
$objDrawingbackground->setDescription('background');
$objDrawingbackground->setPath('Background No Footer.png');
$objDrawingbackground->setCoordinates('E6');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("E8","Some Text");
```

but the text gets hide behide the picture.

I thought about making the the picture transparent and that "should" solve the problem but the users wont be able to select the text.

Does any body have any hint for me? that will be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You'd have to create an image containing the text using GD, then add it to the Excel, because PHPExcel isn't a drawing or graphics library and doesn't provide facilities for editing images

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for the reply, I don't want to modify the picture just put a text on the top of it and it can be selectable, the report that I'm creating is dynamic, so it change with every client. Thank you again!!

Comment: You can't put a text on top of the picture without modifying the picture: pictures are overlaid over the worksheet cells, hiding the cells behind.... you could try a gif with transparency, so that the data in the cells behind would be visible through it; but I've no idea if that would work or not

Comment: +1 because that will works perfect! but the only thing is that the clients won't be able to select the data behind, the picture to copy and past on other reports. I have another question and that is probably is out of my question above, Can I draw a shape using phpexcel, it was feature request from a user, see the request here :  http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/15522  I don't know how much are you following the phpexcel implementations. is that request was implemented on the new version? thank you very much Mark!!

Comment: I do try to keep up to date with the implementations of PHPExcel: Autoshapes aren't supported, even by the latest 1.7.9 version, so this isn't an option. Nor is it likely to be included in the next release either, as that is scheduled to be a major rewrite of core, together with a rewrite of the calculation engine, and a refactoring of the xml-based readers to use XMLREader rather than SimpleXML

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for the valuable info!! adding shapes will be a great future for reporting formatting, will makes client facing reports looks nicer! do you recommend any other packages that has the feature? Thank you again!

Comment: You'll have to rely on [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php), [PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05) or (possibly) [Ilia's](http://ilia.ws/archives/222-PHP-Excel-Extension.html) [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) extension for PHP